# SpriteKit Physics not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I made a sprite according to apple's programming guide, but when the game starts, the sprite should fall (according to the guide), but it doesn't.

Here is how I did it:

```
- (void) createContents {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.6 blue:0.8 alpha:1];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    SKSpriteNode *player = [self newPlayer];
    player.name = @"player";
    player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), player.size.width/1.5);

    [self addChild:player];
}
- (SKSpriteNode *) newPlayer {
    SKSpriteNode *aPlayer = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(40,40)];
    aPlayer.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:aPlayer.size];


    return aPlayer;
}
```

the *createContent* method is called by *didMoveToView*

Why doesn't it, like apple stated in the guide, plummet through the bottom of the screen

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you see the player sprite and it just isn't moving, or is the player sprite just not appearing?

Comment: Okay, this might have been a glitch or I could have missed something, but it's working now

Answer (score 2):

I believe the player did drop to the bottom screen, but it is too fast that you missed it. Since, there is no physical body on the bottom of the screen to stop it and your player is created straight after the scene is shown on the screen.

There are two simple ways to prove it:

- if you set `aPlayer.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;` you will see `aPlayer` node floating around.
- if you change `[self addChild:player];` to `[self performSelector:@selector(addChild:) withObject:player afterDelay:4.0];`, you will surely observe after 4 seconds, `aPlayer` suddenly appear and drop to bottom of the screen

and you should set the Y position of `aPlayer` to higher value to see more of the falling process. In SpriteKit coordinate system, (0,0) coordinate is on bottom left corner

Comment: The Player's position doesn't change, it remains where it's first placed

Comment: need more information how do you initialise your `SKView` and is there anything else in your `SKScene`? Just fyi, I was testing this code on template project on Xcode when you choose Game template. Maybe you can start from there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cmd+Shift+F find to search for a few things.

1. Make sure you haven't accidentally set .dynamic = NO;
2. Make sure you haven't accidentally set the physics world gravity to something undesirable. (Like 0, 0)
3. Very important one... make sure you are initing self.physicsBody such as...

> self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

Answer (score -1):

Likely because you aren't setting the scene's gravity property.

In your SKScene:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,x) // replace x with your desired gravity magnitude and direction (I suggest -9.8)
```

Comment: Gravity is default at (0, -9.81). That shouldn't be the problem.